# What is wrong with my approach for finding a suitable $\delta$ for an arbitrary $\epsilon$?

Tags: limits, inequality, epsilon-delta

I was trying to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to2}x^2=4$ by giving an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. The conventional approach is to first define the $\epsilon$, and then define the corresponding $\delta$, in [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1usUVOhdWIPda3U41I3I3Cz3ekoOMpf-j) way:

I tried out another approach. Instead of showing that $\left|x+2\right|\left|x-2\right|\lt5\left|x-2\right|$, I began by assuming that $\left|x^2-4\right|\lt\epsilon$. Since $3\lt x+2\lt5$ for all $x$ near $2$, I showed that $3\left|x-2\right|\lt\epsilon$ and hence, $\left|x-2\right|\lt\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Hence the suitable $\delta$, according to me, is $\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{3})$.

Looking at the graphs, I see my approach is flawed. For $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{3})$, there are [values of $x$](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F5DRj9E5iV3w7abvxRqIU1ww8ALlEBx7) inside $(2-\frac{\epsilon}{3},2+\frac{\epsilon}{3})$ for which $f(x)\notin(4-\epsilon,4+\epsilon)$. By contrast, the [graph](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1obOWf_pEiaDNXqfkmSMPj609W95NkwMS) for $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{5})$ shows that it is the perfect $\delta$ for any arbitrary $\epsilon$.

I understand there's a logical fallacy in my approach, but I don't understand **what** it is. What is so wrong about $3\left|x-2\right|\lt\epsilon$, but conversely right about $\left|x+2\right|\left|x-2\right|\lt5\left|x-2\right|$? What makes one argument inappropriate, and the other suitable for finding a proper $\delta$?

Comment: It is worth noting that $|(-2)^2 -4| = 0 < \epsilon$, but $3 \not<(-2)+2<5$.

Comment: @DavidKraemer No, since I intended to evaluate the limit at $x=2$ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolating the two inequalities we have that $|x-2| < 1$ and $3 < |x+2|$ but this only implies $3|x-2| < |x+2|$ not $|x+2||x-2| < 3|x-2|$.

However if we use $|x +2| < 5$ we do get $|x+2||x-2| < 5|x-2|$ as desired.

Comment: Didn't see it coming :') Thank you very much